# Android draw area from Bitmap or Imageview with canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview, draw

i'm trying to draw a Bitmap but only with a selected area from the original Bitmap or Imageview. The requirement is that the final picture must show only **1/3** from the top of the original Bitmap. I attach a draft. I suppose that i should use canvas, but i do not know exactly how it works.

Thanks in advance!![image: original pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Bitmap getTheReducedBitmap(Bitmap  fullLengthBitnap)
{    
    Bitmap backDrop=Bitmap.createBitmap(fullLengthBitnap.getWidth(), fullLengthBitnap.getHeight()/3, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas can = new Canvas(backDrop);
    can.drawBitmap(fullLengthBitnap, 0, 0, null);
    return backDrop;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is the documentation for the method you should use.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

```
private void draw(Canvas c, Bitmap bmp){
Rect r=new Rect(0,0,bmp.width,bmp.height/3);
Rect drawR=new Rect(0,0,c.width,c.height/3);
c.drawBitmap(bmp,r,drawR,null);
}
```

or as a one liner:

```
c.drawBitmap(bmp,new Rect(0,0,bmp.width,bmp.height/3),new Rect(0,0,c.width,c.height/3),null);
```

It allows you to specify where on the canvas you want to draw it too, and where you want the segment to be from.

@Eu.Dr. 's answer would not work if you wanted to draw anything else on the canvas below it.

Comment: Thx for your answer but your code do not work cause yo do not make a copy from the original Bitmap, and the final picture would show black on not desired zone instead remove the gap.

Comment: Depends on the size of the canvas. This is if you want to draw other things onto it. In the black space.

Comment: My point is having the final ImageView showing 1/3pic with no black spaces, but i understand that i did not defined this goal more clarify

Answer (score -1):

```
val newBitmap=Bimtap
.createBitmap(your_view.width,your_view.height,Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8)
//note: for tablet mode your_view.width,height will increase drastically so 
//you might want 
//to fix the size of drawing area for optimization
//ALPHA_8 each pixel requires 1 byte of memory.
//RGB_565 Each pixel is stored on 2 bytes
//ARGB_8888 Each pixel is stored on 4 bytes
//after this you can further apply the compress like
[Refer more from google][1]





val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream();
newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
val byteArray = stream.toByteArray(); // convert drawing photo to byte array
// save it in your internal storage.
val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES 
+"attendance_sheet.png");
try{
 val fo = FileOutputStream(storageDir);
 fo.write(byteArray);
 fo.flush();
fo.close();
}catch(Exception ex){           
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it addresses the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.